# MVC asp.net core to webapi service call pass null values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

in request data

[image]

json data

[image]

I don't know, why it pass null values to api?

Update 1

here is my webui action code

```
 const string URLPREFIX = "api/account";
    [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel loginModel)
            {
                var loginFlag = false;
                HttpResponseMessage response1 = await ServiceCall<LoginModel>.postData(URLPREFIX + "/authenticate",loginModel);
                if (response1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    loginFlag = await response1.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>();
                }

                if (loginFlag)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    return View();
                }

            }
```

update 2

```
public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

any try and reply, thanks

Comment: can you show your webapi request code ?

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: Where is the code for loginmodel

Comment: @hitesh the call is right there in the first image

Comment: ok, please show your LoginModel code

Comment: why you are calling Authenticate method from another webapi method you can also call directly

Comment: that's in a another mvc project

Comment: webapi method you can call from anywhere

Comment: @CodingYoshi  i included LoginModel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131461/discussion-between-rajesh-sivasankaran-and-hitesh-thakor).

Comment: @rajesh can you see if you can post the same info to the Authenticate API using Fiddler or another tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Json as a parameter to your controllers, use [formbody] in your web API. It should work. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: i used [frombody] in MVC project it showed blank page when click, but using [frombody] in webApi project it working good, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must add [**ApiController**] in controller level. code is following

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class LoginController : ControllerBase 
{
    const string URLPREFIX = "api/account";
    
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        var loginFlag = false;
        HttpResponseMessage response1 = await ServiceCall<LoginModel>.postData(URLPREFIX + "/authenticate",loginModel);
        if (response1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            loginFlag = await response1.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>();
        }

        if (loginFlag)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must add [ApiController] in controller level. code is following

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]